# Meaning of "Que o casal seja um para o outro de corpo e de mente"

Tags: significado-em-contexto

I have a trouble understanding this sentence
from the Portuguese:

> Que o casal seja um para o outro de corpo e de mente

What is “um para o outro de corpo e de mente”  supposed
 to mean? I just have no idea what this means.

A grammatical explanation would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us where you got it and if anything precedes it. Is it a wedding ceremony from the Catholic Church by any chance?

Comment: @Lambie   It's from the lyrics of "Canção da Família", Christian music, which can be said to be a Brazilian counterpart of gospel music. see (I mean, listen) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IRFxJI0Rm8

Comment: @Lambie Sorry I didn't notice your question. There are many occasions where I celebrate catholic missa at church with those who have their familiy roots in Brazil (or who want jobs in Japan). And it seems that according to their Liturgy, they choose special songs which are appropriate for celebrating particular anniversaries of the church. This song, oracao pela familia, is sung on the day (usually at the end of each year) celebrating the Holy Family.

Comment: Actually, I have now read all about it. By the way,we say Catholic mass in English.  I have no idea what day at the end of the year you are referring to. Do you mean Christmas Day? That celebrates the birth of Jesus.//This is not a counterpart to gospel music, which is Afro-American. This song  was written by a white Jesuit priest who is a formal musician and is Brazilian. He is a composer and musician of Christian music, not to be confused with American fundamentalist music in those mega temples.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a verse from a song ([*Oração pela familia*](https://www.vagalume.com.br/padre-zezinho/oracao-pela-familia.html)), it's been written with some poetic license - for instance, *casal* (couple) is a single entity, singular, so to follow it with *um para o outro* (at/for/to each other) is not quite fitting, even if it clearly refers to the two people that compose the couple.

Here, "to be" (*seja*), literally "exist", can be understood, in a secular way, to stand for "dedicate", "devote", "pledge", or [also](https://www.ufjf.br/pensandobem/programas/filosofando-o-cotidiano/cafe-filosofico/2006-2/)<sup>1</sup> "give (oneself) to" (*entregar a*) or "support" (*ser a favor de*). In this sense, we could translate "*que sejam um para o outro de corpo e de mente*" as

> May they devote themselves to each other, body and mind.

Meaning a wish for them to be committed to each other both physically and mentally.

However, it's worth noticing that the expression actually seems to be customary in religious circles, in the context of couples and relationships. See, for instance:

- the Catholic organization [Comunidade Canção Nova](https://comunidade.cancaonova.com/quem-somos/), which [writes](https://formacao.cancaonova.com/relacionamento/casamento/como-ser-o-melhor-e-mais-fiel-amigo-do-seu-conjuge/) "*o relacionamento a dois alcança a dimensão da amizade, de ser um para o outro*" (the relationship reaches the level of friendship, of being for/to one another);
- the Catholic organization [O Movimento da Palavra de Deus](https://www.mopal.org/pt/ident/index.htm), which [writes](https://www.mopal.org/pt/pasto/CV105_6.htm) "*os parceiros estão realmente chamados a ser 'um para o outro'*" (the partners are really called to be 'for/to one another');
- the verse in the song "[Eu E Você](https://www.letras.mus.br/daniel-samuel/1422106/)", from Daniel and Samuel, "*Para sempre vamos ser um para o outro*" (We will forever 'be for/to one another').

Which might have its origins or even be a reference to the important Catholic document [*Lumen Gentium*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumen_Gentium) (section 35), where [one finds](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19641121_lumen-gentium_po.html) (emphasis added):

> Aí [na família] encontram os esposos a sua vocação própria, de **serem um para o outro** e para os filhos as testemunhas da fé e do amor de Cristo.

In the official [English version](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19641121_lumen-gentium_en.html):

> In such a home husbands and wives find their proper vocation in **being** witnesses of the faith and love of Christ **to one another** and to their children.

In view of that, the verse "*que sejam um para o outro de corpo e de mente*" might be understood as

> May they be [witnesses of the faith and love of Christ] to one another, in body and mind.

<sub><sup>1</sup> [Pensando Bem](https://www.ufjf.br/pensandobem/) | Filosofando o Cotidiano | Café Filosófico | ["O Outro"](https://www.ufjf.br/pensandobem/programas/filosofando-o-cotidiano/cafe-filosofico/2006-2/) (25/03/2006) - Núcleo de Pesquisa em Filosofia e Educação – Departamento de Filosofia da UFJF</sub>

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful to know the use and meaning of "ser de ..." and "um para o outro". Now that I understood most of the song, I can sing it next year.

Comment: Seria bom ter algum tipo de referência aqui. Pelo significado, deve de ser alguma coisa do género, mas _alguém ser para alguém_ só creio ter encontrado no sentido de _ser apropriado para/destinado a alguém_). Encontra-se _Deus seja contigo/connosco_ (_que Deus te/nos proteja_), mas aí a preposição é _com_.

Comment: @Artefacto Good you pointed out the need for references - this made me find that the expression in fact happens to be common in catholic circles and might actually have a different meaning the the (secular) one I'd considered.

Comment: Eu aqui--"Que o casal seja"--hesito entre *may the couple* e *let the couple*, como ja escrevi na minha resposta à outra pergunta sobre a canção. O "que o casal..." pode ser interpretado como desejo do falante ou como exortação a todos os casais, ou até uma combinação das duas coisas. Mas em inglês temos que escolher uma...

Comment: Those translations are abominable, except the Lumen Gentium one. Also, Catholic is capitalized in English. In English we would say here: **that the couple be one in body and mind**. It would be nice to know where  the OP got the sentence and what precedes it. It is impossible to know whether **may** or **let** is appropriate here. As expression of a blessing, it could be either, it would make zero difference. I think that zézinho guy took it from somewhere else. What a rip-off operation he runs.

Comment: @Lambie I'm sorry, but "that the couple be one in body and mind" has little to do with the original sentences in Portuguese. But thanks for the upper case "Catholic" - I trusted the spell checker, but there is the non-capitalized meaning, so it missed it. About the "abominable" translations, frankly, if you find the answer bad, you know how SE works: downvote the answer and, if possible, provide a better one.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, lembrava da tua resposta, e como esse ponto já foi abordado para o OP e é tangente à pergunta, decidi escolher o que me pareceu mais adequado sem comentar a respeito.

Comment: Para sempre vamos a ser um para o otro: **We will always be as one to each other** ser um para o outro: to be as one [to each other].The each other is not need in English, It is understood.

Comment: I made a mistatement about poor old Padre Zezinho. Sorry about that. He seems to be a pretty nice guy. This translation: the partners are really called to be 'to one another') is not right at all. They are called to be as one, we say in English.

Comment: @Lambie I'm convinced you're mistaken: the meaning can't be "to be as one", because then adding "para o outro" wouldn't make any sense - I'm surprised you say it does in English.

Comment: That's right, you don't need para o outro at all in English. It's just to be one or as one.

Comment: We can say "que o casal seja (=os esposos sejam) como um só" (may the spouses be as one). I agree that "que o casal seja uma para o outro" is not quite the same thing; a literal translation would be "may the spouses be for each other", which appears to be more common in English than the Portuguese original. In Portugal we say "temos de ser uns para os outros", meaning 'willing to help each other, be there for each other', but I think "que o casal seja um para o outro" is stonger than that.

Comment: O que a letra realmente quer dizer é "que os cônjuges sejam um para o outro..."  mas acho que não ficaria bem na métrica do verso.  "O casal" soa bem melhor.   @Jacinto sugeriu a palavra ***spouses*** e acho que seria realmente a melhor opção.

Comment: @Centaurus, *spouses* é mais claro que *couple*; mas no que eu insistiria, é em ***for*** em vez de ***to*** (usado na resposta do Stafusa). *Be for one another* parece ser comum, em contexto religioso, e parece-me signifificar o mesmo que *ser um para o outro* ou *uns para os outros*; já *be to one another* é sempre *be [something] to one another* ("how harsh we can be to one another").

Comment: @Jacinto Bom ponto. Obrigado. Adicionei a opção "for" em várias das traduções, omitindo nos casos em que há um 'something' (testemunhas, no caso), ou poderia haver um implícito.

Comment: @Jacinto  agreed.

Comment: Staf, então eu agora insistiria no *for **em vez de** to*; ou para ser mais explicado, acho que onde acrescentaste o *for*, o *to* está errado. *Isto é para ti* é *this is for you*; creio que nunca _*this is to you_; podes dizer é *how important is this to you?* Nós usamos *para* nos dois casos, mas são coisas diferentes

Comment: @Jacinto Então, eu sei, mas discordo, deixei as duas opções conscientemente - a "to" para o caso de de fato os autores estarem fazendo uma referência à expressão do *Lumen Gentium*. Sobre o "important to/for", sim, entendo que [os dois são possíveis](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14484/important-to-me-or-important-for-me).

Answer (score 0):

It means that they will be really together, with their body and also on their thoughts.